# How do i identify the cause of a successful maven build when manually run test via IDE fails?

Tags: macos, maven, intellij-idea, junit, maven-3

I have the following setup:

```
Apache Maven 3.8.1
Maven home: /Users/deyb/.sdkman/candidates/maven/current
Java version: 1.8.0_342, vendor: Azul Systems, Inc., runtime: /Users/myuser/.sdkman/candidates/java/8.0.342-zulu/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_PH, platform encoding: US-ASCII
OS name: "mac os x", version: "12.3", arch: "aarch64", family: "mac"
```

jdk and maven setup installed via sdkman running in a mac m1.

when building the project, i get a successful maven build showing all tests passed without failures.
Triggering the unit test on one of the expected failing classes via ide though shows failed tests results and i cant figure out why it is behaving differently. I am expecting it to fail; but maven build still results in a successful build

To give more context:
example i have a test class of: `com.sample.MySampleTest`

Unit Test Snippet

```
import junit.runner.Version;
...
Set<ConstraintViolation<MySample>> violations = validator.validate(dto);
        log.info("violations count >>> {}", violations.size());
        log.info("JUnit version is: " + Version.id());
        assertThat(violations, hasSize(1));
```

Logs From Maven Build:

```
08:04:22.880 [main] INFO  c.s.MySampleTest - violations count >>> 1
08:04:22.880 [main] INFO  c.s.MySampleTest - JUnit version is: 4.12
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.014 sec
```

Logs from IDEresulting to test failed:

```
08:05:03.431 [main] INFO  c.s.MySampleTest - violations count >>> 0
08:05:03.431 [main] INFO  c.s.MySampleTest - JUnit version is: 4.12

java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: a collection with size <1>
     but: collection size was <0>

    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:956)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:923)
```

I tried the following and got these behavior:

- matched the maven version for both intellij(bundled) and maven via sdk-man results to non failing maven build (expecting to fail but logs show all test runs with 0 failure)
- removed all mvn installations replacing it with the version bundled in the IDE (added the path to intellij plugins to zshrc) results to successful maven build
  `export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/bin"`; also did `chmod` for correct permission but the results are the same
- `run all tests` via intelliJ at `com.sample` package shows failed test in MySampleTest (this is the correct behavior)
- `run all tests` via intellj executed on `com`package shows failed test in MySampleTest (this is the correct behavior)
- `run all tests` via intellj executed on module level shows failed test in MySampleTest (this is the correct behavior)
- reinstalled mvn installation using brew; got successful maven build
- removed junit directories from `.m2` repository for redownload and did a `mvn clean install` also results to successful build
- used a linux machine as build server to run `mvn clean install` results to failed build pointing out the failing test
- added a trivial test `Assert.assertEquals(true, false);` and run it via maven results to failed build (which is expected but only the the trivial test is reported not the test from `MySampleTest`)
- junit version also explicitly declared in the module pom (tested with `junit.runner.Version.id()` to insure matching versions)

Given these behavior, is there any other way to identify what is causing the package/install via maven cli to be successful even if there are failing tests and they are not skipped?

Comment: What is the jdk set to in the "Project" in your IDE? is it the same as command line?

Comment: jdk version in the project is the same both in the CLI and the IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of a procedure, no it's pretty much trial-and-error. However, here are a few more things to try, some of which may or may not be relevant for your specific test:

1. Check you're actually running the same code - i.e. not some code previously checked out in the wrong dir or from the wrong branch, etc. (sounds stupid I know but frequently a problem)
2. Similarly check that any test data it may be loading is the same
3. Are the CLASSPATH settings the same?
4. Ditto for any other environment variables or external resources referenced. e.g. If this isn't a bog-standard collection but something from a ORM, is it talking to the same DB under the hood?
5. Check if there's an ordering issue with the tests. i.e. If you run them in a different order in the IDE do you get different behavior?
6. If this a multi-module maven project? If so, do the tests work if ran in a different order at the module level?
7. Charsets - is there anything in there that's string-sensitive? If so, are the charset settings consistent? (using UTF-8 everywhere is helpful)
8. Is there anything that's timing sensitive. e.g. If the code was delayed either by the IDE or maven could that be a factor?

Comment: 2nd item (and 5) in the list made the difference. Test data was different due to an static initialization on shared lookup (ie an in memory repository used by one of the validators). Concluded that this is more of a design issue. Thanks